The Hyper-V virtual Switch does not allow mirrored traffic to pass through
I have a Hyper-V 2019. My Hyper-V server is connected to a local network where traffic mirroring is configured, I need a virtual machine inside Hyper-v to be able to monitor this traffic.
The server sees mirrored traffic (try wireshark for ethernet connection):
So,I have created a virtual switch (external network) that is attached to the port on which mirrored traffic is hanging.
But after the switch is created, the server does not see the traffic (try wireshark for v-switch connection):
I try this:
>>$ExtPortFeature=Get-VMSystemSwitchExtensionPortFeature -FeatureName "Ethernet Switch Port Security Settings"
>>$ExtPortFeature.SettingData.MonitorMode=2
>>Add-VMSwitchExtensionPortFeature -ExternalPort -SwitchName test4 -VMSwitchExtensionFeature $ExtPortFeature

but it doesn't help. Same result

Make sure the switch set to share with the host OS: "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter" is checked.  Check that the NIC on the VM is set under advanced properties as a port mirroring "destination" in the mirroring mode.  Make sure the NDIS Capture extension is enabled on the switch.

Thanks a lot! My mistake, when creating new VM I forgot to check the mirror destination box
